# Android Studio Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWGTL.png)

Yesterday everything was fine, today when I launched AS this happened. Dont know what to do. I reinstaled AS and SDKs but still. 
This is what i have in gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

and i put this in wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-bin.zip
```

Ive been reading some of the similar posts here, but they dont work for me, maybe cause they are old!?
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this is just stupid how AS deals with errors. The problem was my button_blue.9.png file. Dont know why but when I deleted it, with those 2 lines still under coments, and rebuilded it, it regenerated my R.java.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delete the cache data from your pc.
You can see this folder in your User folder Example. `C://Users/Your_PC_Username/.gradle`
and .AndroidStudio2.2   Both folder delete it and reopen your android studio.

It's select new install and also please check your internet is connected. It's will download your gradle files again and all cache files and settings save again.

I hope it works.

Comment: OK thx, I found the problem. R.java got deleted, dont know why. I saw on other posts that if .xml file is bad than it would delete R, but mine were OK, and I did clean rebuild after but it didnt create new R.java :/

Comment: @Nemanja    
You shouldn't need to manually create with R.java at all. It can be re-generated from the android studio source code. Thus, it is likely that you won't have any problems -- R.java will be auto-generated and all will be well. If it isn't, try a rebuild of the project. The important part is that your R.java is found here under build/source/<flavor>/r/<build (optional)>/<package>/R.java

Comment: Well it happened again, and I think its the same reason as the last time! I just added 2 lines `buttonLeft.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blue);
buttonRight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_blue);` and build the project just in case, and it deleted my R.java. I tried clean project, rebuild project and even invalidate caches/restart after I put those 2 lines in comment but it still wont generate new R.java

Comment: OK, I found the problem again. Now this is just stupid how AS deals with errors. The problem was my button_blue.9.png file. Dont know why but when I deleted it, with those 2 lines still under coments, and rebuilded it, it regenerated my R.java.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution is to place the code below in the module `build.gradle`:

```
android { 
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

And Sync the Project.